# Windows - FMX - Invalid Class Typecast C++

Tags: c++, c++builder, firemonkey

I'm facing a little trouble when trying to run a function through a DLL.
I get the following error when executing the function (it compiles normally):

> Invalid Class Typecast

Here is the code:

```
#include <fmx.h>
#define CRIPTNSDLL_EXPORTS
#include "CriptLib.h"
#include <FMX.Memo.hpp>
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <string.h>

#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Cript_BasicoM (String Original, String Chave, TMemo* Memo){

    if (Original.Length() != Chave.Length()) {
        throw Exception (L"Não é possível encriptar o conteúdo.\nO tamanho das palaras chave e original não podem ser diferentes.");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Chave.Length(); i++) {
        for (int p = 0; p < Chave.Length(); p++) {
            if (Chave.c_str()[i] == Chave.c_str()[p] && p != i) {
                throw Exception (L"Não é possível encriptar o conteúdo.\nA chave não pode ter dois caracteres iguais.");
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Original.Length(); i++) {
        for (int p = 0; p < Original.Length(); p++) {
            if (Original.c_str()[i] == Original.c_str()[p] && p != i) {
                throw Exception (L"Não é possível encriptar o conteúdo.\nA palavra original não pode ter dois caracteres iguais.");
            }
        }
    }

    String Linha = NULL;

    Memo->BeginUpdate();

    for (int i = 0; i < Original.Length(); i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < Memo->Lines->Count; k++) {
            Linha = Memo->Lines->Strings[k];
            for (int l = 0; l < Linha.Length(); l++) {
                if (Linha.c_str()[l] == Original.c_str()[i]) Linha.c_str()[l] = Chave.c_str() [i];
                else if (Linha.c_str()[l] == Chave.c_str()[i]) Linha.c_str()[l] = Original.c_str() [i];
            }
            Memo->Lines->Strings[k] = Linha;
        }
    }

    Memo->Lines->Add(Original);
    Memo->Lines->Add("CriptB");

    Memo->EndUpdate();
    Memo->Repaint();

}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef CriptLibH
#define CriptLibH

#ifdef CRIPTNSDLL_EXPORTS
#define CRIPTLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CRIPTLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus

#include <fmx.h>
#include <FMX.Dialogs.hpp>
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <string.h>
#include <FMX.Memo.hpp>

extern "C" {
#endif

    CRIPTLIB_API void Cript_BasicoM(String Original, String Chave, TMemo* Memo);
    CRIPTLIB_API void Cript_BasicoL(String Original, String Chave, TStringList* Lista);
    CRIPTLIB_API void Cript_BasicoS(String Original, String Chave, String Linha);
    CRIPTLIB_API void Decript_BasicoM(String Chave, TMemo* Memo);
    CRIPTLIB_API void Decript_BasicoL(String Chave, TStringList* Lista);
    CRIPTLIB_API void Decript_BasicoS(String Original, String Chave, String Linha);
    CRIPTLIB_API String VerProg();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}

namespace CriptLib
{
    class Encriptar
    {
    public:
        static void Subst(String Original, String Chave, TMemo* Memo) { Cript_BasicoM(Original, Chave, Memo); }
        static void Subst(String Original, String Chave, TStringList* Lista) { Cript_BasicoL(Original, Chave, Lista); }
        static void Subst(String Original, String Chave, String Linha) { Cript_BasicoS(Original, Chave, Linha); }
    };

    class Decriptar
    {
    public:
        static void Subst(String Chave, TMemo* Memo) { Decript_BasicoM(Chave, Memo); }
        static void Subst(String Chave, TStringList* Lista) { Decript_BasicoL(Chave, Lista); }
        static void Subst(String Original, String Chave, String Linha) { Decript_BasicoS(Original, Chave, Linha); }
    };

    class Info
    {
    public:
        static String Ver() { return VerProg(); }
    };

}
#endif

#endif
```

Evoking the function (also where the exception is thrown):

```
CriptLib::Encriptar::Subst(edtOriginal->Text, edtKey->Text, memoContent);
```

Debuger description:

> First chance exception at $77303E28. Exception class EInvalidCast with
>   message 'Invalid class typecast'. Process Project1.exe (7476)

I've found the exact position of the problem. It is when using Memo->Lines->Count for comparison into the for structure. To make sure I created an integer variable and tried to equalize with the Count property and using it into for (even casting like int(Memo->Lines->Count)). However I also got the error. (Now using debugger). I strongly believe it shouldn't be happening, once the property Count returns an integer value (and I used this expresion many times).

Since now, THANKS A LOT.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to identify where the exception is being thrown, and if not why not?

Comment: It just shows the address of the error, but I don't have any idea how to identify it. So, I decided to put try blocks in every step of the code and the exception is thrown when running for.

Comment: post a complete but minimal example that readers can try

Comment: Just added the compiler debug info, I don't know if it can really help

Comment: A debugger will show you where the exception gets thrown from, complete with a stack trace. If whatever you're using doesn't give you that, then it fails to meet the definition of "debugger". Without either a complete backtrace showing the location of the error, or a "Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example" (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information) nobody will have the sufficient information to be able to help you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for the advice.
I've found the exact position of the problem. It is when using Memo->Lines->Count for comparison into the for structure. To make sure I created an integer variable and tried to equalize with the Count propriety and using it into for (even casting like int(Memo->Lines->Count)). However I also got the error. (Now using debugger). I strongly believe it shouldn't be happening, once the propriety Count returns an integer value.

Comment: I've tried to fix it by myself. However I still don't know where I did something wrong (I know where the error is happening. However I don't know why I can't use Count property to compare into for, once I've made it a lot of times without any error or exception).

Comment: Passing objects across DLL boundaries is a general problem. You have to make sure that both sides used exactly the same compiler and linker switches (that is, the DLL and also the code invoking the DLL), and linked against the exact same runtime libraries.  Even then it might not work.

Comment: @M.M Yes, I'm shure. I've compiled both at the same compiler and used the same resources, options and linkers.
I've tried using a previous version of the compiler and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an RTL bug. Since I was using the XE8 version it came with a bug in the System.Classes file. You can check it here:

> [Bug fix list for RAD Studio 10 Seattle](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/44561)

You will have to search for the QP# (RSP-11445)

I'm sorry to trouble you.